# OpenGL - OS X using GL11

Tags: java, macos, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I was developing a game in Java & OpenGL on Windows and yesterday I got a new Macbook Pro.
When I moved my code from the Windows machine to the OS X machine I got an error that said couldn't compile shaders. I read on the internet that it's because in OS X you have to turn ProfileCore to true which is only supported in OpenGL 3.2 + . Here is my problem: For my GUI and my Text I use GL10 functions and I use the Slick2D library. When-ever I set my OpenGL version to be 3.2 with core profile the game runs fine but I get an error on Slick2D code.

- I wanted to know if there was a way to run OpenGL with core profile but not 3.2
- Is there a library for text like Slick2D that supports OpenGL 3.2 or will I have to create my own support of texture atlases and stuff for the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I must write this as an answer.

The core profile is a configuration in OSX which sets the used OpenGL version.
https:// developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/

Slick2D should support lower OpenGL Versions. I have used it with OpenGL version 2.1 on Linux and Windows. My Application also ran in OSX.

Try out core profile version 2.1. This is the version that was most compatible to PCs (and Macs) in my testing.

I do not fully understand your second question. Are you looking for an alternative engine?
I can recommend libGDX for cross-platform game development with Java. (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

If you are open to non-Java Game Engines, you can use Unity3D of course. (http://unity3d.com/)

Comment: That is actually not correct. Core profile is an OpenGL feature, not one specific to OSX. And OpenGL profiles were just introduced in GL3.2. Hence there is no GL2.1 core profile. OSX now supports only legacy GL up to GL2.1 _or_ modern GL with a >=3.2 _core_ profile, which is not backwards compatible to older GL versions.

Comment: @derhass So basically what you are saying is that I need to choose between GL 1 - 2.1 or 3.2+ ?

Comment: @GeorgeClone-y: Yes. Note that also the open source mesa drivers also follow OSX' example here: they also support modern GL only in a core profile. And that is actually fully complying the spec, since only core profile is required, compatibility is optional.